# Is there auto-syncing in netbeans for external changes

Tags: netbeans, synchronization

I know netbeans syncs the original files once I save, but if there is a file changed externally is there a way for netbeans to recognize this and either tell me to re-sync it or automatically resync it with the new changes?

Comment: For me NetBeans (7.4) automatically reloads a modified file if I put the focus back to the IDE. I didn't configure anything for that.

Comment: I've been testing mine and I'm actually an eclipse user... So I synced the server's files with netbeans and if I change something in eclipse and upload it and go back to netbeans, the change doesn't show. If I try to open the file on netbeans it does not warn me that it has changed and its as if nothing actually changed.

Comment: I was talking about files accessible in the local filesystem. Are you talking about FTP access to a server? I have never used that in NetBeans

Comment: Yes I am, I work in Hawaii while the rest of my office is in Indiana.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what makes this behavior possible:

> NetBeans 6.9 contains a feature that automatically looks for external changes to keep informations about files up-to-date. We have some reports that it can slow down NetBeans mainly, when an open project has many folders. When NetBeans find out that files were externally changed, it re-scans the files to keep data up-to-date that are used with features like code completion, navigation etc. Unfortunately the notification and following re-scanning can take some time and during this time many mentioned features are waiting for the finishing of scanning. There is option Enable auto-scanning of sources that can switch off this behavior. The option you can find it in Options dialog, Miscellaneous category and Files tab.
>
> The default behavior is that NetBeans also looks for external changes when the main window gets focus. This is can be during developing a web application very often when user switches between browser and IDE. The mentioned option also switch this off.
>
> When you switch off  option Enable auto-scanning of sources you can still keep the information up-to-date, just invoke Scan for External Changes  action from Sources menu manually.

(Here's the [original article](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/enable-auto-scanning-of-sources-scan-for-external-changes) by Petr Pisl)

I find it counterproductive to leave this setting on, as sometimes auto-loading external changes to a file opened in the UI without asking for permission first can ruin your day when you're forced to make small local changes that you don't want replicated in your repository. I'm sure other people can think of more reasons to advocate for "warn before loading external changes" behavior to be implemented in NB. That is one of the reasons why I like Eclipse better sometimes.

Comment: Could you include the essence of the solution in your answer, as it otherwise might become useless if the linked website changes or goes offline.